# Raspberry Pi in mineral oil enclosure

Tags: raspberry-pi, insulation, humidity

I have a project based on a Raspberry Pi. It is intended to work outside, but I thought that humidity will destroy the Pi and the electronics board. I thought about creating a perfect waterproof enclosure for the electronics, but it's very hard.

Therefore I want to know: Is there any problem to put the Pi and the board in a container full of mineral oil?

It seems to me that mineral oil is an electrical isolator and it will block humidity from the environment from reaching my Pi. Any suggestion about that idea?

Comment: Do you really need to seal it? I'd expect a drip-proof enclosure would be adequate for active electronics in the UK - so long as its mounted well clear of the ground, and you're not at a coastal location.

Comment: Computers in mineral oil are generally there for heat management rather than moisture - mineral oil absorbs enough humidity to be an issue in high voltage systems that transformers have to have systems to remove it. I'm not sure if it will matter with something extra low voltage, but something which is hydrophobic rather than hydroscopic would be better.

Comment: If you put the board in mineral oil you would still have to use a sealed container to contain the oil. I don't get how this is much easier than just using a similar container to keep water out.

Comment: It's because the air is very wet where the device will be placed, so I want to avoid contact between air and board

Comment: @JamesMagnus Ordinary glass mason jars (used for canning) are a cheap way to make an air-tight sealed enclosure.  For external connections put an IP67 or better circular connector into the metal lid.  You can probably get both the jar and connector for under ten dollars.

Answer (score 4):

Just buy a can of conformal coating spray and put it on the board.  That will protect everything but the connector pins from humidity.

https://www.aitechnology.com/products/conformal-coatings/conformal-coating-moisture/

https://www.techspray.com/c-4-conformal-coating.aspx

Comment: A lot of thin conformal coatings are still hydroscopic

Comment: @TonyStewart Sorry, I'm not English, what do you mean by "hydroscopic" ?

Comment: hydro (water) scopic ( absorbs)

Comment: @TonyStewart if you care about moisture then you just need to make sure the one you use is labeled as moisture resistant.

Comment: not easy ...Traditional acrylic, epoxy and polyurethane conformal coatings are not hydrophobic and does not provide adequate protection in heavy moisture and particularly susceptible to salt-fog and otherindustrial corrosive gases in heavy industrial and traffic environments.
Silicone based conformal coating while hydrophobic to water but allows very high moisture penetration (most as much as 5 to times of the rate of acrylic conformal coatings) and also susceptible to the same attacks of high concentration of moisture

Comment: -1. This is why this suggestion is a bad (insufficient /vague inaccurate) answer http://www.aitechnology.com/uploads/videos/conformal-coating-video.mp4. no clean flux will corrode your copper with sealed moisture like all apple products

Comment: @TonyStewart I like the coating you recommended.  I added it to the suggestions.  The purpose of my answer was not to recommend a specific coating, but rather to recommend that coating may be much easier than a mineral-oil enclosure.  Where I work we clean and coat our boards and they typically have very long service lives.

Comment: @TonyStewart Actually, the word you wanted is **hygroscopic**. Hydroscopic would be in reference to a device called a hydroscope for peering into water. I think it's a little inconsistency in English.

Comment: perhaps,I should have used hydrophobic, it seems many suppliers use both terms ..  actually Hydro = water,   Hygro = humidity and perhaps hydrophobic means repels water , like most plastics and ** hygrophobic means repels water vapour, ** which most plastics do not. Since the gas molecules may be absorbed.

Answer (score 2):

The countless projects of people putting full ATX sized pc boards in mineral oil successfully would suggest this would be fine on a smaller scale like the RPi.

That said, the long term environmental benefits are unknown. The RPI'S long term life span is also unknown. It likely won't live much longer than it would unprotected. The cost of mineral oil and a water tight enclosure would be more than a replacement, and a replacement would likely be an upgraded model.

Comment: I'm watching videos about x86 PC in aquarium of oil. And it seems to work, even with the 110/220 V -> 12/5/3 V transformer

Comment: oil only doubles the crosstalk with dielectric constant of 2 but connector leaks are hard to prevent.

Comment: @TonyStewart: More importantly, it will alter the impedance of any microstrip transmission lines, which are designed assuming there's air on one side. This could lead to serious signal integrity issues on any high-speed serial connections, such as HDMI and USB3.

Comment: yes and any memory bus signals may be marginalized too, but then so could solder mask and conformal spray if on outer layers. critical signal usually have no mask.

Comment: On the other hand, the board is quite small, so any transmission lines will only be slighly affected.

Answer (score 0):

- conformal spray has a higher dielectric constant like plastic or epoxy than oil.
- coating d=~ 4-5
- oil =~ 2
- air = 1
- water = 80

Now the question is will the crosstalk from coupling capitance cause errors and lower for controlled impedances.

- If you can prevent a leakage, it might work.
- Connector interfaces will be a big problem though using pressure tight bulky connectors.

Comment: On my board there is no high speed signal or very sensitive device.  So I think it's not a problem to change capacity but for the pi I'm think there could be a problem with the SD card slot

Comment: oh ok no rise times <0.1us

Comment: @james only if you try to insert a card in the already submerged pi. Maybe. The contact force is plenty to squeeze it out.

Comment: You might give this stuff a look.  I've seen it used exactly once for electronics.   http://www.agmcontainer.com/products/vpci.html

Comment: ...or you might paint the board with silicone grease.  I've seen that done.